# Woocommerce - Copy New Order Details to New Table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I found the below script somewhere on here before and having trouble getting it to work. Basically I want to copy basic order details into a new table (which is in the same database), so I can run some reports off of it from non wordpress page. I have changed the table name and fields and copied this into my functions.php in the theme. But it doesnt seem to do anything. Any help would be great, im really stuck. I'm running woocommerce 2.2.8 if that makes any difference.

```
function add_neworders ($order_id) {
global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$total = $order->order_total;
$date = $order->order_date;

global $wpdb;
$table =  $wpdb->prefix . 'finacedata';

$wpdb->insert($table, array( 

'desctipion' => $name, 
'status' => '2',
'date' => $date,
'amount' => $total,
'invoice' => $order_id,
));

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_neworders' );}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a late answer, but the `woocommerce_new_order` action runs when the order is created, but the data is not populated just yet, so everything is empty.

Use the `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` action instead, which runs when the order is created and all of the order data(like line items) are stored.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add add_action into function. put outside the function:

```
function add_neworders ($order_id) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $total = $order->order_total;
    $date = $order->order_date;

    global $wpdb;
    $table =  $wpdb->prefix . 'finacedata';

    $wpdb->insert($table, array(

    'desctipion' => $name,
    'status' => '2',
    'date' => $date,
    'amount' => $total,
    'invoice' => $order_id,
    ));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_neworders' );
```

Comment: Thanks for that... For some reason it still doesnt do anything when a new order is created. Its there anyway to see if its creating an error at all?

Comment: you can print $order_id;exit; as it's going to function. $name is not defined.so check for that

Comment: Hi, this still doesnt appear to print anything. Not sure the woocommerce_new_order is being called..